# What is the purpose of off-loading definitions with autoload in emacs? Why not autoloading is slow?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In ELisp, you can skip the evaluation of a definition with the autoload cookie. The definition is evaluated only once it's used.

```
;; File foo.el

;;;###autoload
(defun foo ()
  "Doc"
  42)

(defun bar ()
  "Doc"
  43)
```

So, *if I understand correctly* the autoload functionnality is a hack to load file faster. But when I load `foo.el`, in order to skip the definition of foo the interpreter still has to read the whole form. I don't understand why it's faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to load the content of the file `foo.el` is to do a `load`.
However, this is costly because you have to read the whole file.

With `autoload` you are allowed to tell emacs: "function `foo` is defined in file `foo.el`".
This way emacs does not read the file and you do not pay the loading price. When you use the function `foo` for the first time, emacs will find the definition for you by reading `foo.el`.

The `;;;###autoload` comment in your file is not doing anything for autoload by itself.
You need to use a program that will grab all of these definitions and put them in a file `foo-autoloads.el` (or any other name).
For each function it will put a line telling emacs which file contains it.
Then in your `.emacs` you will `load` `foo-autoloads.el` instead of `foo.el`.
`foo.el` will be read by emacs the first time you use function `foo`.

Note: `require` can also be used instead of `load` in the explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get that "understanding" from?  Certainly not the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).

The autoload cookies are used to pull out skeletal function/variable definitions in a separate autoload file.  This is usually done at compile time.

Without going through that compilation step the autoload cookies have no effect.

Comment: What is the point of this separate autoload file? [This email](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-05/msg00388.html) says that autoloading may accelerate emacs startup. Why?

Comment: Autoloading certainly does accelerate start-up, however providing an autoload cookie *is not the same thing as autoloading*. The cookie is a *hint* to an external manually-initiated process that it should include the following form when *generating a file* of autoload expressions. That file is invariably called "loaddefs.el". You can examine the main one with `M-x find-library RET loaddefs RET`. The "point of this separate autoload file" is that Emacs then does not have to read the libraries containing the autoload cookies *at all* until one of those functions is called.

Comment: Because if the autoloads are in the same file then you gain nothing, because the file is loaded anyway. That's what your question is about. The autoloading forms have to be in a separate file, so only they are loaded (quickly) and the whole file containing the actual definitions is loaded only if one of the autoladed functions is called.

Answer (score 1):

The autoload forms have to be loaded separatly. They can be generated from the autoload cookies, but you can also write them manually. For example, in your .emacs you can put autoload forms for functions which you only use occasionally, so they are only loaded on demand.

For example:

```
(autoload 'ahk-mode "ahk-mode")
```

Comment: knarf: Note also that while this is the simplest way to use autoloading in your own code, it is good form to include appropriate autoload cookies in any libraries you may make available for third-party consumption, as package-managers like el-get can utilise them automatically.